# Jsoncpp - access array element inside an object?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Is there a "proper" way to extract an element of array which is a child of an object in JsonCPP?

I'm dealing with JsonRPC objects along the lines of:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "data": [{
            "state": 7,
            "stateticks":362220
        }],
        "ticks": 416410
    }
}
```

If I want to pull the first (or, n-th, for that matter) element of the array, by doing

```
  Json::Value& sessionData = object["result"]["data"][0];
```

I'm getting the error of:

```
 error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const Json::Value’ and ‘int’)
 116 |                 Json::Value& sessionData = object["result"]["data"][0];
```

I can bypass this by creating an intermediate variable:

```
  Json::Value& allSessionData = object["result"]["data"]; 
  Json::Value& sessionData = allSessionData[0];
```

but I'm also dealing with nested arrays and generally I don't like multiplying helper variables like that and I bet there is a better way... can you help?

Comment: Which jsoncpp version and which compiler? Do you get the same error if you use `object["result"]["data"][0u]`?

Comment: @Michael Wish I knew where to find it, no version# in any header - but `0u` works. I still wonder what type is the generic literal `0` so that Jsoncpp doesn't recognize it as int.

Comment: `json.h` contains the version number. But the compiler may also matter. I can't reproduce this with jsoncpp 1.8.4 and Clang.

Comment: @Michael my json.h is 8 lines, literally code guards and 4 includes. Maybe my jsoncpp is just so old - the project has been around for a good while. Regardless, `0u` or just casting to int solves my problem.